# how to access a local variable in another function?

Tags: c++, class

I just go through an interview where i was asked how can i access local variable of function to other function.
code flow-

```
class A{
    public:
    void fun1(int a){
       int local_var=a;
    }
    
    void fun2(){
        // here i want to use local_var of fun1
        //you are not allowed to do any changes either in fun1 and class
        // however you can do anythingh in fun2.
    }
  
}
```

is there any way to do it.

Comment: If `local_var` goes out of scope the moment `fun1` returns and you're not allowed to modify the function, clearly, you can't read the value in any other scope.

Comment: Now if you're willing to trigger UB, it's possible that adding a similar `int` stack variable to `fun2` without ever initializing it, and calling `fun2` immediately after `fun1`, may end up getting you the original value of `local_var` as the "trash" value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Local variables *do not exist* if the function is not *currently executing* and even then, they only "exist" in a very narrow *scope*.

Here `local_var` is a short-lived `int` that only springs into being during `fun1` executing. The instant that function is done, it's gone.

`fun2()` has no access to it because it doesn't exist at that point. Even if you call `fun2()` within `fun1()` it still doesn't have access because `fun2()` has its own local scope that's different.

If you want something shared you need either a *property* on your class if this should be shared within a single member of this class, or a `static` variable if it's shared between *all* members.

What you probably mean is this:

```cpp
class A{
public:
  int m_a = 0;

  void fun1(int a) {
     m_a = a;
  }
    
  void fun2() {
     // Can use m_a here
  }
}
```